# Derivative of a bijective smooth function is invertible?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

Suppose now I have a $1-1$ mapping $F$ from $U$ onto $V$ and $F \in C^{1}$, I want to know if we can say $F'(x)$ is invertible? if so, how do we prove it?

Comment: You can't say that $F'$ is invertible. Consider $U = V = \mathbb{R}$ and $F(x) = x^3$. $F$ is bijective but $F'(0)$ is $0$ (not invertible).

Comment: @Matsmir Why not an official answer?